# Incorrect understanding of implicit conversion from reference to std::reference_wrapper or compiler bug?

Tags: c++, reference, implicit-conversion, reference-wrapper

I'm confused about some code involving references and std::reference_wrapper and I'm not clear at all whether this is my fault since I'm misunderstanding how reference wrapper works or if I hit a compiler error.

I have a simple map, pairing a reference to an object from a complex class to a value:

```
std::unordered_map<Object const &obj, int32_t value> myMap;
```

(for simplicity, I explicitly left out the hash and equal functors required by the map to compile)

Since I can't directly use the reference in the map, I use a reference wrapper to it:

```
std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object> obj, int32_t value> myMap;
```

Now, my map is populated in a function such as:

```
void myFunction(Object const &obj, int32_t value)
{
    ...
    myMap.emplace(std::make_pair(obj, value));
}
```

but that code, although compiles, doesn't work. However, this one works as expected:

```
void myFunction(Object const &obj, int32_t value)
{
    ...
    myMap.emplace(std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int32_t>(obj, value));
}
```

(notice in this second version I'm still not explicitly building a reference wrapper to obj)

So, my doubt is:

Am I misunderstanding something about the usage of reference wrapper? There's no implicit conversion from reference to reference_wrapper? If not, why does the code compile in the first place?

Or is this a known issue/flaw in std::make_pair not being capable to correctly deduct the types passed to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_pair` never<sup>(1)</sup> deduces a reference type as one of the types in the pair, it always produces value types. So the call to `emplace` receives a *temporary* `std::pair<Object, int32_t>` as argument. The reference wrapper is then initialised from this temporary, meaning that it will bind to the `first` member of this *temporary* pair.

In the second case, the temporary is of type `std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int32_t>` (since you've explicitly requested that), which means that there's a reference wrapper in the temporary pair, bound directly to `obj`. The reference wrapper inside the map is then copied from this temporary reference wrapper and thus refers directly to `obj`.

<sup>(1)</sup> "Never" is not true here. There's one exception: when one of the arguments to `std::make_pair` is of type `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, the type in the pair will be decuced to `T&`. Which actually provides the correct solution for you: wrap `obj` in `std::cref` inside the `make_pair` call:

```
myMap.emplace(std::make_pair(std::cref(obj), value));
```

This will then cause the temporary pair to contain a reference, and the `reference_wrapper` inside the map will bind to its referred object (`obj`), which is precisely what you want.